# Can you embed DBCC Shrinkfile into a IF statement?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I have an issue where my maintenance job Transaction logs do not always shrink when `DBCC SHRINKFILE`  is run.
My thought was to place `DBCC SHRINKFILE` within an if statement that checks the size of the log file and if it is > the value I enter to keep running till it is below that value.

I have found I can pull the data from
`select size from sys.database_files where name = 'DB_log'`
but when I try to place `DBCC SHRINKFILE` I can not get it to like any syntax?
Is this just a limitation of Database Console Commands?

```
select size 
    , case when size > 10210 then (DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'db_log' , TRUNCATEONLY) else end
    from sys.database_files
```

Greatest thanks from a SQL Novice!

Comment: Why do you shrink the transaction log ? What is the recovery mode of the target database ? What is your backup plan on that database ?

Answer (score 3):

This is what you need.

```
SELECT 
 size, 
 shrinkStatement=
 CASE 
  WHEN size > 10210 THEN '(DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''db_log'' , TRUNCATEONLY)' 
  ELSE 'do not shrink'
 END
FROM sys.database_files
WHERE type_desc ='Log'
```

Before you deploy this, I suggest you read this article by Brent Ozar and all other articles referenced in that.
[Stop Shrinking Your Database Files. Seriously. Now.](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/)

You want to collect your log file usage over time and keep it at your average usage size instead of shrinking it every time it grows.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: don't shrink your database files! You have already been pointed to [Brent's article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/), I have [my own](https://karaszi.com/why-you-want-to-be-restrictive-with-shrink-of-database-files) and if you google it, you'll find an endless stream of articles on this topic.

Having said this, in case you *really* insist on doing this:

Your proposal seems strange. You use CASE inside a SELECT. In there you try to construct a SQL command. This doesn't execute anything, by itself. Perhaps you want to generate an SQL command and use dynamic SQL to grab that SQL command tand EXEC(@sql)? If so, you have been given a pointer already.

Else, then you should construct the shrink command in a variable, and based on some condition use IF statement (not CASE expression) to conditionally do execute that shrink command that you have in your variable. And perhaps you want a WHILE loop around this to keep going until you reached your target size. Just a rough pointer in case you want to pursue this.

But if your system need, say, 100GB log space for the operations you do, then just count that as a cost for your system instead of keep shrinking the file and have it growing over and over and over and over again.